# Using TLS with Serilog.Sinks.Email?

Tags: serilog

Can TLS be used with Serilog.Sinks.Email, and if so, how?  I can't seem to find any options or documentation on this (other than a suggestion that "EnableSsl = false" defaults to TLS)

Using:  .NET Framework 4.6.2, Serilog 2.8, Serilog.Sinks.Email 2.3

My Code:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Email(new EmailConnectionInfo
    {
        FromEmail = "xxx",
        ToEmail = "xxx",
        MailServer = "smtp.xxx.com",
        EmailSubject = "My Test",
        EnableSsl = false,
        Port = xxx,
        NetworkCredentials = new NetworkCredential
        {
            UserName = "xxx",
            Password = "xxx"
        }
    }, batchPostingLimit:1
    ).CreateLogger();

Log.ForContext<Program>().Error("Test Number {Parm}", "1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes, [`Serilog.Sinks.Email`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-email#serilogsinksemail) uses .NET's [`SmtpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8) to send the e-mails, so all you have to do, is:

- Set `EnableSsl` to **`true`**
- Set the `Port` to a port that support TLS in the server (usually port **`587`**, but check with your IT guys)

---

You can read more about how [`SmtpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8) uses TLS/SSL in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl?view=netframework-4.8):

> The SmtpClient class only supports the SMTP Service Extension for
>   Secure SMTP over Transport Layer Security as defined in RFC 3207. In
>   this mode, the SMTP session begins on an unencrypted channel, then a
>   STARTTLS command is issued by the client to the server to switch to
>   secure communication using SSL. See RFC 3207 published by the Internet
>   Engineering Task Force (IETF) for more information.